# How to generate multiple reCaptcha Enterprise checkbox-key tokens without checkbox

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

We are using ReCaptcha enterprise (checkbox based site key) for our registration page.

Using check-box key (over score based key) is recommended in [Google Doc](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/choose-key-type) for pages like user registration.

Site based key provides a checkbox that user always has to hit, which generates reCaptcha token. ReCaptcha token cannot be used twice, as its assessment just states token is duplicate.

If we have multiple API endpoints to protect, how do we get multiple re-captcha tokens without making user hit the checkbox for each endpoint?

Comment: Where in those docs do you get the impression that the checkbox site key is preferred over the score based? There is a note that suggests the opposite "We do not recommend using checkbox site keys because they increase user friction and don't significantly improve accuracy."

Comment: Correct, but in use-cases section, `Checkbox site keys are appropriate for forms, logins, and signups on web pages.` 
This is very confusing to me as a reader, author mentions checkbox is appropriate for registration, but also stating they don't recommend checkbox.

For our scenario, in new user registration, if bot detected, checkbox key makes sense as it presents a challenge.
If use score based key is used, only thing I can think of is to send a verification code to their number/email, which can be spammed.